# Blocking Internet access of some app

Tags: android

I want to block internet access of some certain apps.
As UID (User ID) is unique for each application and stays constant as long as app is not re-installed.Is  it possible to block the internet access of app on the basis of UID? For Non-rooted phone

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with rooted phone, you can [install iptables](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.iptables) and set up firewall rules that blocks all internet traffic for that user:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m owner --uid-owner $UID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $UID -j DROP
```

Comment: No i am asking for a non-rooted phone thanx any way

Comment: No, you need root access to mess with other applications

Comment: Is there any way through packets as i am capturing packets without root access?

Comment: You can create a VPN Service that is used for capturing packets on newer Androids and filter the packets in it but using it is not reliable, any application can easily bypass it if it wants.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is rooted and your app is running as root, then yes it is possible.  Or, if your app is running as a System app on the device, it is also possible.  For any other condition, it is not possible.